# How can a relational database with foreign key constraints ingest data that may be in the wrong order?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, referential-integrity, data-ingestion

The database is ingesting data from a stream, and all the rows needed to satisfy a foreign key constraint may be late or never arrive.

This can likely be accomplished by using another datastore, one without foreign key constraints, and then when all the needed data is available, read into the database which has fk constraints. However, this adds complexity and I'd like to avoid it.

We're working on a solution that creates "placeholder" rows to point the foreign key to. When the real data comes in, the placeholder is replaced with real values. Again, this adds complexity, but it's the best solution we've found so far.

How do people typically solve this problem?

**Edit**: Some sample data which might help explain the problem:

Let's say we have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE order (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  order_number,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE (order_number)
);

CREATE TABLE line_item (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  order_number INTEGER REFERENCES order(order_number),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

If I insert an order first, not a problem! But let's say I try:

`INSERT INTO line_item (order_number) values (123)` before order 123 was inserted. This will fail the fk constraint of course. But this might be the order I get the data, since it's reading from a stream that is collecting this data from multiple sources.

Also, to address @philpxy's question, I didn't really find much on this. One thing that was mentioned was [deferred constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html). This is a mechanism that waits to do the fk constraints at the end of a transaction. I don't think it's possible to do that in my case however, since these insert statements will be run at random times whenever the data is received.

Comment: Can you add some sample data which helps to explain the problem?

Comment: What did your research show? [ask] [help]

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added an example to the question.

Comment: If you are not looking for consistency at end of the transaction, then when(at what time) data should be in the consistent state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a business workflow problem, because line items of individual orders are coming in before the orders themselves have come in.  One workaround, perhaps not ideal, would be to create a before insert trigger which checks, for every incoming insert to the `line_item` table, whether that order already exists in the `order` table.  If not, then it will first insert the order record before trying the insert on `line_item`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."fn_insert_order" () RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO "order" (order_number)
    SELECT NEW.order_number
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "order" WHERE order_number = NEW.order_number);
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

# trigger 
CREATE TRIGGER "trigger_insert_order"
BEFORE INSERT ON line_item FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_insert_order()
```

Note: I am assuming that the `id` column of the `order` table in fact is auto increment, in which case Postgres would automatically assign a value to it when inserting as above.  Most likely, this is what you want, as having two id columns which both need to be manually assigned does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish that with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on `line_item`.
In that trigger you query `order` if a matching item exists, and if not, you insert a dummy row.

That will allow the `INSERT` to succeed, at the cost of some performance.

To insert rows into `order`, use

```
INSERT INTO order ...
ON CONFLICT ON (order_number) DO UPDATE SET
   id = EXCLUDED.id;
```

Updating a primary key is problematic and may lead to conflicts. One way you could get around that is if you use negative `id`s for artificially generated orders (assuming that the real `id`s are positive). If you have any references to that primary key, you'd have to define the constraint with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.